# Запрет адаптивности Vue + Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Необходимо сделать две версии сайта на поддоменах (m.app.com и app.com), каждая имеющая свое приложение на Vue+Vuetify. 
Так как шаблон приложения на Vuetify по умолчанию адаптивен, то необходимо сделать его с минимальным значением ширины в 1200px (к примеру). Пробовал присваивать значение .v-container в style компонента, но это не привело к необходимому результату. Пытался вставть inline, результата положительного так же не получил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был найден в добавлении css правила в корневой компонент приложения (application.vue)

```
....
<style>
html {
  min-width: 1200px;
  max-width: none !important;
}
</style>
```